# cannot print from the server computer when client isn't connected

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer, network-printer

I have two computers (km1 and km2) which are connected to each other and km1 is server. My printer is HP Laserjet 1020. Both systems have Windows 7 - 64 Bit.

Whenever I connect printer to km2 which is the client, I can print from both computers. But when I connect printer to km1 which is server and I completely shut-down km2, I cannot print. I tried reinstalling the drivers for about three times and the computer recognizes the printer and when I disconnect it, the Icon in "Devices and Printers" grey out so I am sure it recognizes the printer but despite this, I cannot print from server when client is shutdowned and printer is connected to server computer.

Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: You must install 2 printer copies on each computer - local printer (on USB port) and network one (on network share). And then select a proper printer to print.

Comment: @Akina There is two icons in devices and printers of km1 (server), "HP Laserjet 1020" and "HP Laserjet 1020 on km2" and when I shut down km2, "HP Laserjet 1020 on km2" grey out but "HP Laserjet 1020" don't grey out until I unplug it. So  I Think there is 2 printer installed but whenever I want to print something with "HP Laserjet 1020" It doesn't (without any printer sound - no printing error). I deleted the "HP Laserjet 1020" three times and reinstalled the driver but nothing changed. I really don't know what other thing I should do

Comment: What driver do you use? where does it's taken from? try [HP LaserJet 1020 Plus Full Feature Software and Driver](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-1020-printer-series/439423) (don't forget to select proper OS defore downloading) - remove both copies of printer on both computers, connect printer to one of them, install it on both, move printer to another comp and again install (if soft asked, select "Install new printer").

Comment: @Akina I'll try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Because the km1 does not be shared successfully, we need to set the sharing setting of km1 again.

**Step 1: Turn on file and printer sharing.**

1.Open Network and Sharing Center.

2.Click on Change advanced shared settings, in the left pane.

3.Click on the down arrow, which will expand the network profile.

4.Select File and printer sharing and choose Turn on file and printer sharing.

5.Click on Save changes.

**Step 2: Share your printer.**

1.Click on Devices and Printers, from the popup list.

2.Right click the printer you want to share. A dropdown list will appear.

3.Select Printer properties from the dropdown list.

4.Click on the Sharing tab.

5.Select the Share this printer check box.

**Step 3: Ensure the two computer are in the same groupwork.**

Note: The shared printer is a printer in a LAN that everyone can use, but if the computer sharing the printer is not turned on, we will not be able to use it.